# Partition does not start on physical sector boundary. Partition table entries are not in disk order

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, fdisk, partition-table

I am a new Manjaro user, my 1TB hard disk is showing two overlapped partitions, its shows two more partitions at the end that I don't recognize. I can't delete it using KDE partition manager. How do I fix it? thanks.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes   
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2f3a4562

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048     716799    714752   349M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2           718848  978272255 977553408 466.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3        978272256 1481621503 503349248   240G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       1481623550 1953523711 471900162   225G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       1481623552 1911683071 430059520 205.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb6       6206652416 6222276607  15624192   7.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7       1911685120 1953523711  41838592    20G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

[image]

Edit:
cat /proc/mounts

```
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
sys /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
dev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1934316k,nr_inodes=483579,mode=755,inode64 0 0
run /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755,inode64 0 0
efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars efivarfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,noatime 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
none /sys/fs/bpf bpf rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=12729 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tracefs /sys/kernel/tracing tracefs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,noatime,inode64 0 0
/dev/loop1 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2128 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop2 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11798 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop3 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2246 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop7 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1169 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop4 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/11993 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop5 /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1081 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop6 /var/lib/snapd/snap/git-cola/136 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop9 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop8 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gitkraken/184 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop0 /var/lib/snapd/snap/bare/5 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop10 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gitkraken/183 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop11 /var/lib/snapd/snap/inkscape/9090 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop13 /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/13270 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop12 /var/lib/snapd/snap/inkscape/9256 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop14 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop15 /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1519 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop16 /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/13640 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop17 /var/lib/snapd/snap/spotify/52 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/loop18 /var/lib/snapd/snap/spotify/53 squashfs ro,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=388812k,nr_inodes=97203,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
portal /run/user/1000/doc fuse.portal rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sdb5 /run/media/aravind/E fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb3 /run/media/aravind/New\040Volume fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /run/media/aravind/New\040Volume1 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdb2 /run/media/aravind/EEB47B8FB47B5953 fuseblk ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`
```

`head /sys/block/sdb/sdb*/{start,size}`

```
==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb1/start <==
2048

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb2/start <==
718848

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb3/start <==
978272256

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb4/start <==
1481623550

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb5/start <==
1481623552

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb1/size <==
714752

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb2/size <==
977553408

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb3/size <==
503349248

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb4/size <==
2

==> /sys/block/sdb/sdb5/size <==
430059520
```

Answer (score 1):

Partition 4 is extended so its alignment does not matter in practice, some partitioners do that and it can be ignored.

However the partition sdb6 seems to be out of bounds (starts at 3.18TB on a 1TB disk) and the graphical partitioner seems to be confounded by it (shows 1.98TiB unallocated space on a 931.51GiB drive, which is not possible).

Now the question is, how did this partition come about and what kind of data would you expect to find there? Sometimes there are programs that do shenanigans with the partition table (to hide partitions or map filesystem files as partitions) but I'm not sure about the purpose in this context.

It does show /dev/sdb6 as being mounted to /run though. Not sure what's happening there.

Double check `cat /proc/mounts` (what's mounted where) and `head /sys/block/sdb/sdb*/{start,size}` (partitions as the linux kernel sees it).

Comment: I was just checking out the KDE partition manager. I am not fully sure of what I did but after that, the 1.98 TiB unallocated showed up (they were not present initially). I have data in other partition but don't think there is anything in the unallocated partition.

Comment: Hope this is what you meant. let me know if anything more is needed. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Also, GParted is showing: "cant have overlapping partitions", "cant have partitions outside disk". and i believe the sda6 mounting to /run is the swap partition that i created for manjaro.

Comment: Can you put this info by editing your questions? Comments have a max length (this is why I posted my comment as an answer ^^; ) and it seems to be cut off.